# Getting "free(): invalid pointer" with a custom TCL interpreter

Tags: c++, malloc, free, tcl, glibc

I have a custom TCL interpreter. Here it is:

```
// file main.cpp
#include <tcl.h>
#include <string>

int    argc = 0;
char** argv = 0;

int
Tcl_AppInit( Tcl_Interp* interp ) 
{
    if ( Tcl_Init( interp ) == TCL_ERROR ) {
        return TCL_ERROR;  
    }
    for ( int i = 1; i < argc; ++i ) {             
        if ( Tcl_Eval( interp, ("source " + std::string( argv[i] )).c_str() ) == TCL_ERROR ) {
            return TCL_ERROR;
        }
    }
    return TCL_OK;
}

int
main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    ::argc = argc;
    ::argv = argv;
    Tcl_Main( 1, argv, &Tcl_AppInit );
    return 0;
}
```

I build `main.cpp` with the following command:

```
g++ -DNDEBUG -O3 -fpic -Wall -pedantic -fno-strict-aliasing \
    -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -ltcl main.cpp -o myinterp
```

Sometimes `myinterp` crushes with an error message like this:

```
free(): invalid pointer: 0x00002b04078aa000 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3723c722ef]
/lib64/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4b)[0x3723c7273b]
/lib64/libc.so.6(_IO_free_backup_area+0x18)[0x3723c6e1d8]
/lib64/libc.so.6(_IO_file_overflow+0x1d2)[0x3723c6c1d2]
/lib64/libc.so.6(_IO_file_xsputn+0xf2)[0x3723c6ce22]
/lib64/libc.so.6(_IO_vfprintf+0x1b0)[0x3723c428a0]
/lib64/libc.so.6(_IO_fprintf+0x88)[0x3723c4d358]
```

Is something wrong with `main.cpp`? What could cause this crash?

Answer (score 2):

You might be better off writing the code like this:

```
int
Tcl_AppInit( Tcl_Interp* interp )
{
    if ( Tcl_Init( interp ) == TCL_ERROR ) {
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }
    for ( int i = 1; i < argc; ++i ) {
        std::string script("source ");

        script += argv[i];
        if ( Tcl_Eval( interp, script.c_str() ) == TCL_ERROR ) {
            return TCL_ERROR;
        }
    }
    return TCL_OK;
}
```

Like that, the lifetime of the buffer in the `std::string` will be correct, which is what my intuition indicates is probably your real problem. (Once there's corrupted memory about, the crash can crop up nearly anywhere.) However, you should also be aware that this will still go thoroughly wrong if you've got spaces in any of those filenames. Maybe that's OK for you (e.g., if it's all local filenames with “nice” names) but otherwise use Tcl's [`Tcl_EvalObjv`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclLib/Eval.htm) to do the execution, like this (which is a bit longer; it's really C, not C++):

```
int
Tcl_AppInit( Tcl_Interp* interp ) 
{
    Tcl_Obj *script[2];
    int code = TCL_OK;

    if ( Tcl_Init( interp ) == TCL_ERROR ) {
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }
    script[0] = Tcl_NewStringObj("source", -1);
    Tcl_IncrRefCount(script[0]);
    for ( int i = 1; i < argc && code == TCL_OK; ++i ) {
        script[1] = Tcl_NewStringObj(argv[i], -1);
        Tcl_IncrRefCount(script[1]);
        if (Tcl_EvalObjv(interp, 2, script, 0/*no special flags*/) != TCL_OK) {
            code = TCL_ERROR;
        }
        Tcl_DecrRefCount(script[1]);
    }
    Tcl_DecrRefCount(script[0]);
    return code;
}
```

Comment: Consider the case with "nice" filenames. I don't think there is a problem with call `Tcl_Eval( interp, ("source " + std::string( argv[i] )).c_str() )`. The temporary `std::string` object for which I call `c_str()` exists until the end of the block where it is created right? So it is being destroyed at the end of each iteration at `for` loop, so during the execution of `Tcl_Eval` that temporary object still exists. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Vahagn: That's the kind of assumption that I'd be *very* cautious about using. Plus you could use `Tcl_VarEval` to have Tcl do the concatenation for you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Tcl_Main should be like this:

```
Tcl_Main(argc, argv, Tcl_AppInit);
```

without the addressof & operator.  See here  [here](http://www.gibmonks.com/practical-programming/ch44lev1sec6.html) for an example. I take it you are fibbing to Tcl_Main about the size of argv in order to bypass the automatic processing of arguments?

Edit: For what its worth, I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code, but then given my mental aberration over the address of operator my opinion might not be worth much. Can you source the scripts into a standard tclsh interpreter without any problems? Do they load any other extensions or libraries?

Comment: `Tcl_AppInit` and `&Tcl_AppInit` are identical.

Comment: Doh - yes of course it is, and more correct as well as it shows you really meant to take the address rather than call the function.

Comment: @Jackson Yes I am fibbing about the size of `argv`. The purpose of writing this custom TCL interpreter is to have a situation when `myinterp some.tcl` processes `some.tcl` and does NOT exist the interactive TCL session. If you could suggest another better way to achieve this then I will be grateful.

Comment: @Vahagn: http://wiki.tcl.tk/1968 has some code (in the comments; click to reveal) that implements a command loop (i.e., REPL) in pure Tcl. Just have a script that includes that code and you'll be able to interact with the Tcl interpreter despite loading code from a file. Or you can use the more-polished stuff from the Tclx package.

Comment: @Donal Fellows I was using the Tclx package but it yield to some problems with Tk. After `commandloop -interactive on` all GUI hangs if you don't call teh `update` command permanently.

Comment: @Vahagn: OK, then use one of the scripted versions that calls `vwait` somewhere internally. They will all let Tk work.